# select random entry using two columns

Tags: mysql, random

I created a contest where people who refer others increase their odds of winning with each referral. Now I have to figure out how to use mysql or php to actually give them better odds. Selecting a random row won't cut it.

In my table I have two columns, one for ID and one for the referral ID. The table keeps track of who referred whom by adding the ID into the referral ID field, so the first few rows of data looks like this:

```
name   id  referralid 
mark   15   20 
ted    20 
jim    22   20
```

So 'ted' should have 3 chances to win since he referred two other people. How can I do this in mysql or php?

Comment: sorry, if I wasn't clear, I need a mysql command to grab an entry from the db that will actually give better odds to ted.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT people.name, people.id
FROM people
LEFT JOIN people referred_people ON referred_people.referralid = people.id
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 1
```

Assuming your table is called *people* this selects

```
mark
ted
ted
jim
```

sorts that randomly using the infamous ORDER BY RAND() construction (slow but you didn't ask for maximum performance) and then chooses one result from that list.

Comment: something isn't working.... my query returns only the column name 'name'. quite a newby here.          SELECT 'name'
FROM register
LEFT JOIN register referred_register ON referred_register.referral = register.id
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 1

Comment: I changed the "name" to * and it is pulling the entire row of information, but there are duplicate columns listed for some reason.

Comment: Edited to better suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.name,b.Odds
from (select referralid,count(1) Odds from    yourtable
group by referralid) b inner join yourtable a
on a.id=b.referralid
```

Comment: You can replace `case when referralid='' then 1 else 1 end` with `1`. And you could replace `case when referralid='' then 1 else 0 end` with `referralid=''`. And you probably mean `SUM` instead of `COUNT`.

Comment: Oh, it was `COUNT(*)`you meant, ok. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this::

Why dont you get a random number and get the row for that number and then the id to which the referralid points in that row will win.

Say With this given data, say the random number if generates 1 or 3.
You will have ted pointed in both the rows.